# Why do some chars have two unicode numbers?

Tags: unicode

Let's take the left single quotation mark: `‘`.

It's Unicode number is `U+2018`.
However:

1. In HTML you represent it as `&#8216;` and it's called the character’s "Unicode numeric entity".
2. In CSS you can use \2018 as in `content:'\2018';`.
3. In Windows you get it by typing `Alt`+`0145`.

Why is that?

Comment: What does `Alt-0145` have to do with Unicode ?

Comment: There's probably a char with U+0145 assigned to it? I don't know.

Comment: There is, but U+0145 is a hexadecimal code and `Alt-xxxx` uses decimal codes. Furthermore, 145 decimal is 91 decimal, and U+0091 certainly isn't a ‘.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was answering your question out of context. Basically I added the Windows shortcut out of curiosity on why it's different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number in the HTML entity reference 8216 is decimal (base 10); the Unicode codepoint and CSS escape sequence 2018 are hexadecimal (base 16). They are the same number in different bases.

In HTML, you can express the same character in a hexadecimal entity reference using the [`#x` notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.3.1): `&#x2018;`

In CSS, [only hexadecimal numbers are allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters).

The left single quotation mark is represented as (decimal) 145 in the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding.

Comment: Although unrelated and purely out of curiosity, any idea why Windows uses something else. I don't think `0145` is also a different number base.

Comment: That I'm not sure, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) has something to say about it. I think it's for the most part unrelated.

Comment: Thanks again. [extra chars]